# Parsing and data overwriting issues in C using custom strtok

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I'm reading in a .csv file, which I then need to parse into tokens.  I tried using strtok(), but that unfortunately cannot return null fields (which my data is fulll of).  So I went with a home-made version of strtok that I found, strtok_single, which returns the correct values that I need.

The data is input into my array correctly; but there is something wrong because before the initilization loops finish, the data gets overwritten.  I've tried print statements and analyzing the problem but I just can't figure out what's wrong.  Any insight at all would be helpful.

Here is the homemade strtok function I'm using:

```
char* strtok_single(char* str, char const* delims) {
    static char* src = NULL;

    char* p, *ret = 0;

    if (str != NULL)
        src = str;    
    if (src == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if ((p = strpbrk(src, delims)) != NULL) {
        *p = 0;
        ret = src;
        src = ++p;
    }    
    return ret;
}
```

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int numLines = 0;
    int ch, i, j;
    char tmp[1024];
    char* field;
    char line[1024];

    FILE* fp = fopen("filename.csv", "r");

    // count number of lines in file
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            numLines++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // Allocate memory for each line in file
    char*** activity = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char**));

    for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        activity[i] = malloc(42 * sizeof(char*));

        for (j = 0; j < 42; j++) {
            activity[i][j] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        }
    }

    // read activity file and initilize activity matrix
    FILE* stream = fopen("filename.csv", "r");
    i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream)) {
        j = 0;
        int newlineLoc = strcspn(line, "\n");
        line[newlineLoc] = ',';
        strcpy(tmp, line);

        field = strtok_single(tmp, ",");

        while (field != NULL) {
            for (j = 0; j < 42; j++) {
                activity[i][j] = field;
                field = strtok_single(NULL, ",");
                // when I print activity[i][j] here, the values are correct
            }
            // when I print activity[i][j] here, the values are correct for the
            // first iteration
            // and then get overwritten by partial data from the next line
        }

        i++;

    } // close while
    fclose(stream);

    // by the time I get to here my matrix is full of garbage
    // some more code that prints the array and frees memory
} // close main
```

Comment: You say the input is CSV; is it a fixed format or a variable number of columns?

Comment: It's a fixed format of 42 columns, but a variable number of lines. Hence why I was lazy and just hardcoded the 42, instead of making a variable for columns.  I'll improve that later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activity[i][j] = field;
```

When the loops finish, each `activity[i][j]` points to somewhere in `tmp`, which is overwritten in each loop. Instead, since you pre-allocate space in each `activity[i][j]`, you should just copy the contents of the string to that:

```
strcpy(activity[i][j], field);
```

Being careful of buffer overflow (i.e. if `field` is more than 99 characters).

Also, the `sizeof(char)` is superfluous since it's always 1 by definition.

Comment: Wow, field is a moving pointer to tmp and I'm overwriting tmp, it's so clear in hindsight thank you.   Also, though I know sizeof(char) is 1, I always put the sizeof(type) in my mallocs just to keep in the habit (better to put it when it's not necessary than to forget it when it is necessary).  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Your line "activity[i][j] = field;" is backwards - you want the pointer assigned to the malloc'd memory.